# How to compile and use modified ejabberd source files

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, ejabberd, production-environment

I have ejabberd server v16.03 running, (written in `erlang 18.3`), which I downloaded from [ejabberd site](https://www.ejabberd.im) for `ubuntu`.

I want some custom tasks to be done by server.
So I have modified `ejabberd_c2s.erl` file.
When I compile it from source using `./configure` `make` `make install`, it compiles without any errors.

But when I run it using `ejabberdctl start` it doesn't run the changes I made.
So, I need to use debugger `ejabberdctl debug` and attach the module `ejabberd_c2s.erl` only then changes I made works.

Even the logs don't show any changes after debug mode enable or disabled.

**I want my changes to be work on production server.**

Any suggestions will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this-
syntax - erlc -I include_hrl_file_path  -o ejabberd_binary_file_path(output path)  sourc_file_path

```
example-
erlc -I /opt/ejabberd-16.03/lib/ejabberd-16.03/include -o /opt/ejabberd-16.03/lib/ejabberd-16.03/ebin  ejabberd_src/ejabberd_c2s.erl
```